# Binding a boolean expression in a polymer element

Tags: polymer

I have an array of objects which I am displaying using a table via a polymer template.

The following simple expression produces a column of "true" or "false", as expected, from the 'player' boolean field

```
<td>{{player}}</td>
```

however, I can't find any expressions that also work, they all produce no output. None of the below work:

```
<td>{{!player}}</td>
<td>{{-player}}</td>
<td>{{player+1}}</td>
<td>{{player?'a':'b'}}</td>
```

Is this is deliberate restriction in polymer-expressions, or am I doing something wrong? I have polymer-expressions.js from Aug 8, 18156 bytes.

Andy

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that there's an error elsewhere in your code. The given expressions all work, take a look at this demo: http://jsbin.com/towiro/1/edit

```
<polymer-element name='my-elem'>
  <template>
    <style> td {padding: 10px; border: 1px solid black; width: 40px;}
    </style>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>{{player}}</td>
        <td>{{!player}}</td>
        <td>{{-player}}</td>
        <td>{{player + 1}}</td>
        <td>{{player?'a':'b'}}</td>
    </table>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('my-elem', {
      player: true
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```